# Formatting Slug {postDate.month} to 2 characters

Tags: postdate, craft-pro

We are migrating our site into Craft, which is by and far easy and pleasant. But I'm trying to match our old CMS's permalink structure, which used 2-character months in the URI.

When defining the structure to contain our old content, I'm unable to format the **postDate.month** as I'd like. I thought the Twig below would work, but it's giving me the wrong digit for the month (or example it should be '07' but consistently gives me '12'):

```
{postDate.year}/{postDate.month|date('m') }/{slug}
```

I'm sure this is pretty simple, but I can't pin down the syntax. Could someone please give me a hand?

I need a URI like this:

```
2015/07/here-is-my-slug
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should just be able to do:

```
postDate|date('m')
```

`postDate` by itself should give you a DateTime object which you can then apply the filter to.

Comment: You should include that the reason he's getting 12 by using `postDate.month|date('m')` is because PHP is trying to build a date solely on the number seven.

Comment: Fair comment, I didn't know that :)

Comment: KAPOW! That did it -- and of course trying to parse the 'm' from something already extracting the month is going to give me bad results. I just changed the URI format and it's just what I needed. Thanks.